# Can't understand the lambda function inside the sorted() key argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, lambda

I have to sort a string in this order:

- All sorted lowercase letters are ahead of uppercase letters.
- All sorted uppercase letters are ahead of digits.
- All sorted odd digits are ahead of sorted even digits.

For instance, when the input is "Sample6789", the output must be "aelmpS7968."

The code that solved this problem was the following:

```
s = 'Sample6789'
print("".join(sorted(s, key=lambda x: (x.isdigit(), x.isdigit() and int(x)%2==0, x.isupper(), x))))
```

So, as far as I understand, the lambda function checks whether it's digit, even, and uppercase or not, and returns it. But I am not sure how it actually iterates through every letter/digit and returns the desired output. For example, if I understand correctly, the first letter "S" gets tuple of (False - not integer, False - not integer and not even, True - upper Case, S - itself). But after that, I have no clue how is it returning the correct output.

Comment: The callback to `sorted` does not do any sorting.  The callback itself does not iterate over anything.  The callback returns a *key*, and `sorted` sorts elements based on how it would naturally sort the elements' keys.  Tuples are sorted element-wise, and `False` is ordered before `True`, so an element with key `(False, False, True)` would be ordered before an element with key `(False, True, False)`.

Comment: @jamesdlin, why not make that an answer?  I'd upvote it.

Comment: @jamesdlin sorry, I didn't clearly express what I meant (English is my third language.) I couldn't understand how lambda function in key argument specifies the way to sort the elements. If I understood your explanation correctly, Tuples are sorted in this way: if I had (False, True, True) and (True, False, False) tuples, the former will be arragned first, and then the latter? So, at first, all the tuples with three "False" will appear, then with one "True" at the end and lastly, the ones with "True" at the beginning?

Answer (score 2):

As the comment notes: tuples are sorted such that False is ordered before True

```
first x = "S" --> (False, False, True, "S")
        = "a" --> (False, False, False, "a")
        = "m" --> (False, False, False, "m")
        = "p" --> (False, False, False, "p")
        = "l" --> (False, False, False, "l")
        = "e" --> (False, False, False, "e")
        = "6" --> (True, True, False, "6")
        = "7" --> (True, False, False, "7")
        = "8" --> (True, True, False, "8")
        = "9" --> (True, False, False, "9")
```

so

```
sorted(s, key=lambda x: (x.isdigit(), x.isdigit() and int(x)%2==0, x.isupper(), x))
```

gives:

```
['a', 'e', 'l', 'm', 'p', 'S', '7', '9', '6', '8']
```

then .join() -- does this help?

Comment: Makes sense. I didn't know that tuples are sorted that way. Thanks for clarification!